# Is it possible to click a CommandButton programmatically via the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I have an Excel Workbook that contains VBA macros that perform certain calculations on the sheet. The macros are protected and triggers by the click of CommandButtons. Because of the protection, I can't see which macros are triggered by which buttons, so I can't run the macros directly.

I need to use the calculations in a C# project, so I use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace to open the file and write the input values to the necessary cells. But to get the output values I need to run the macros. Is it possible to click the CommandButtons programmatically or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can focus it and send an Enter-key press, as a workaround.